# Manipulation of log file using python

Tags: python

I'm the following log file structure. I want to find out the maximum response time and want to print the log file which is having the highest response time(R.T) using python 2.7.11.

**The structure of my log file:**

```
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed 4.0(R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed 6.0(R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed 5.0(R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed 8.0(R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed 2.0(R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
```

**Used Code:**

```
file =open(r"logfile.txt","r")
rts = []
for line in file:
line_array = line.split(" ")
rts.append(float(line_array[10]))
max_rt = max(rts)
print "Max R.T is :", max_rt
```

**Output:**

```
2.0
2.0
5.0 
8.0
8.0
```

**Query**

The for loop is executing the all the lines and printing the intermediate response time.Finally highest response  time is printed.

**Help me!!**

To print only the highest response time

To print the  entire log file having the highest response time.

How to store each and every string in a DICTIONARY and retrieve the data which is need eg.(If data is specified .the code should print the highest response time)

```
       1     2 3   4                    5     6   7   8        9     10          11
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed 4.0(R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
```

Comment: You code cannot yield the output you describe. You will get a `ValueError` from trying to convert e.g. `4.0(R.T)` to a float. Please provide a (correctly indented) MCVE - [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the questions is a little confusing, I think this will help. After reading the log you can sort the lines using a lambda function as the key in the built-in sorted function. You just have to specify where the response time is in the line. I did this by splitting the line then referring to the response time by it's index position. The comments in the code below may make it more clear.

```
# open the log file
with open('logfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    # read lines into list (one item per line)
    data = f.readlines()
# sort the data by response time descending using lambda as key
sorted_data = sorted(data,
                     # response time is at index 10 in the split line
                     key=lambda row: row.split()[10],
                     reverse=True)
# print the row with the highest response time
print(sorted_data[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for your info.

Comment: The data which is having the float values 0.0 is only printed by this code. The values having 00.000 are missed and not been printed. Help me!

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
import re

with open(r"logfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines_and_times = []

for line in lines:
    RT = re.findall('(\d+\.\d+)\(R\.T\)', line, re.DOTALL)
    if RT:
        lines_and_times.append((float(RT[0]), line))

lines_and_times.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0], reverse=True)

print 'Max time: {}'.format(lines_and_times[0][0])
print 'Full log:'
print lines_and_times[0][1]
```

returning:

```
Max time: 8.0
Full log:
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed 8.0(R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
```

Using a regex lets us find the response time for each line, which we store as a tuple alongside the full line. We then sort a list of these tuples according to the response time (`reverse=True` gives us descending order) and print the information from the first entry in this list.

Comment: Thanks for your info